# how to kill a process group using Python subprocess

Tags: python, subprocess, kill, child-process, festival

I am trying to do the equivalent of the following using Python subprocess:

```
>cat /var/log/dmesg | festival --tts &
[1] 30875
>kill -9 -30875
```

Note that I am killing the process *group* (as indicated by the negative sign prepending the process ID number) in order to kill all of the child processes Festival launches.

In Python, I currently have the following code, wherein two processes are created and linked via a pipe.

```
process_cat = subprocess.Popen([
    "cat",
    "/var/log/dmesg"
], stdout = subprocess.PIPE)
process_Festival = subprocess.Popen([
    "festival",
    "--tts"
], stdin = process_cat.stdout, stdout = subprocess.PIPE)
```

How should I kill these processes and their child processes in a way equivalent to the Bash way shown above? The following approach is insufficient because it does not kill the child processes:

```
os.kill(process_cat.pid, signal.SIGKILL)
os.kill(process_Festival.pid, signal.SIGKILL)
```

Is there a more elegant way to do this, perhaps using just one process?

Comment: Why is it insufficient? Maybe have a look at `os.setprgid`

Comment: It is insufficient because it does not kill the child processes of Festival. I'll edit the question for clarity.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can simplify this a lot as you rarely need `cat |`. Eg:

```
process_Festival = subprocess.Popen(["festival", "--tts", "/var/log/dmesg"])
```

then later

```
process_Festival.send_signal(1)
```

If you kill festival with a signal like SIGHUP rather than SIGKILL it
will clean up any subprocesses properly.

---

There's a very good explanation of [how to create a new process group](https://pymotw.com/2/subprocess/#process-groups-sessions) with python subprocess.  Adding option `preexec_fn=os.setsid` to Popen:

```
process_Festival = subprocess.Popen(["festival", "--tts", "/var/log/dmesg"],preexec_fn=os.setsid)
```

You can then get the process group from the process id and signal it:

```
pgrp = os.getpgid(process_Festival.pid)
os.killpg(pgrp, signal.SIGINT)
```

Note: since Python *3.2* you can also use `start_new_session=True` in the `Popen` call instead of `preexec_fn`.

Comment: Hi there. Thank you for your simplification suggestion. You are quite right in this case (though I want to use pipes for other more elaborate purposes). Regarding your ```send_signal(9)``` approach, the problem is that this is equivalent to something like ```kill -9 30875``` as opposed to ```kill -9 -30875```. Your approach does not kill the many child processes created by Festival, which is what I need.

Comment: there is an `os.killpg(pg,signal)` and process_Festival.pid is the process id.

Comment: dont use kill -9 but -1 so festival can clean up its children.

Comment: Thank you very much for your suggestions. I need to kill the process *group* rather than get Festival to terminate the child processes, because the child processes can continue running for a very long time before they are terminated, which is inappropriate for my purposes. Do you know how to use the ```os.killpg``` function with subprocess? It doesn't appear that it can be used with the PID returned by a single subprocess process.

Comment: there is an `os.getpgid(pid)` to get the process group from a pid.

Comment: Hmm, this is probably a silly question, but how should I get ```os.getpgid``` to not kill the Python script that is running it? Things seem to work when I use the argument ```preexec_fn = os.setsid``` when creating the process, but I don't understand it.Thanks again for all of your ideas on this.

Comment: If you mention this in your solution, I'm happy to accept it.

Comment: I have found a good article about the difference between sessions and process groups. http://www.andy-pearce.com/blog/posts/2013/Aug/process-groups-and-sessions/ . So, if you want to spawn a daemon process, you need to use `os.setsid` or `start_new_session` parameter. But if you are spawning just child processes which should die at the moment when you are logging off from the terminal, prefer to use `preexec_fn=os.setpgrp`